# How to know PDO execute query UPDATE successful?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this query:

```
UPDATE account 
SET password = :newpw 
WHERE id = :id 
  AND password = :oldpw
```

I try to input wrong passwd but `$stmt->execute` always return true - why?

Comment: where your php code?

Comment: Please put your full code. because no one can say what is wrong by seeing this one line

Answer (score -1):

Check [PDOStatement::rowCount](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php)

it will return 1 in case row was updated and 0 if not.